# MySQL query and relational table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a table called `Item`:

```
(id int primary_key, item_name varchar, packing_list int)
```

packing_list is the number of the Items in a single carton, and another table called `Invoice`:

```
(id int primary_key, quantityOfCarton int).
```

quantityOfCarton represents the total number of cartons for an item.

Assume that i have these values:

> Item (1, Nutella, 3); // id, item_name, packing_list
>
> Invoice (1, 2) // id, quantityOfCarton

So I have two Nutella cartons, and in each carton, there are 3 Nutella jars.

I want to calculate the total number of Items (Nutella jars), and the formula is as follow:

```
totalItems = quantityOfCarton * packing_list; // 3*2= 6 Nutella jars.
```

My problem is with the query that will retrieve the data that are necessary for the formula, and how the tables should be related?

I want something like this:

```
SELECT item_name, packing_list 
FROM Item and SELECT quantityOfCarton from Invoice where item_name= "nutella ";
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would select item_name when you are specifying `where item_name=`.

Anyway, it sounds like you want:

```
select quantityOfCarton * packing_list
from Item
join Invoice on Item.id=Invoice.id
where Item.item_name='nutella';
```

If you are frequently looking up items by name, you should probably have an index on item_name.

Comment: yea sorry i meant where id=1; so how these tables should be related in keys? should **id of item** be a **foreign** key in the invoice table?

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen  for the query to work, it just needs to be an index, and it already is a primary key.  but having Invoice.id be an item id seems a little odd; would you ever have an invoice without an item, or an item without an invoice?  or more than one invoice for an item?

Comment: @SOreadytohelp yea there are more than one invoice for an item, actually the system define all items in the stock, than by time start making invoices for the predefined item

Comment: then Invoice should have an item_id foreign key and the item id should not be stored in Invoice.id

Comment: and then you want something more like `select item_name,sum(quantityOfCarton * packing_list) from Item join Invoice on Item.id=Invoice.item_id where Item.id=?`

Comment: @SOreadytohelp may i ask a last question, what is the syntax of the query that will add the foreign key, many thanks in advance